# Ruby, How to match strings from one file with another file and print the matched strings

Tags: ruby, arrays, matching

I have two files. File1:

```
ruby,amazing,awesome
```

file2:

```
ruby-443-543-fx\n
amazing-122-454-nx\n
hello-432-544-lx\n
awesome-522-65-nx\n
```

How to do I run a search to match file1 word with file2 line (for example, amazing from file1 to be matched with amazing-122-454-nx)? Then, I need to print the matched results as followings:

```
ruby-443-543-fx\n
amazing-122-454-nx\n
awesome-522-65-nx\n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
words = File.read("file1.txt").strip.split(/,/)
words_regex = Regexp.union(words)

File.open("file2.txt").each do |line|
    puts line if line =~ words_regex
end
```

Output:

```
ruby-443-543-fx
amazing-122-454-nx
awesome-522-65-nx
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if my first file contains this:          hii-mee-ruby,amazing,awesome                                                  Your answer was exactly, what I was looking for, but what if I don't want the hii-mee- ? how do I get rid of them?

Comment: That's a significant change to what you posted. You'd need to determine how to parse the words to extract what you want. Do you drop everything before the last '-'? If so, add `.map{ |w| w.sub(/^.*-/, '')}` to the first line.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your `file1` to be a one-per-line list of words you want to search for, you can just use `grep`, the friendly Unix-y searching tool:

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

This will certainly be faster than anything you could build in Ruby.

If you want to remove newlines from the result, you can do that with the `tr` command, like so:

```
grep -f file1 file2 | tr -d "\n"
```

Comment: But, what I need is to find a match for each word separated with comma (for example: ruby from the file1) and match it with the file2. and print out the output for the matched lines.

Comment: ** I included \n to show that the file2 is 3 lines. and file1 is only one line.

Comment: I still maintain that `grep` is the way to go. Try this: `grep "$(cat file1 | tr "," "\n")" file2`. This only will work up to a certain limit though (probably up to at least 260 KB for file1).